# Fatal Exception in React Native Android

Tags: react-native

```
10-09 15:32:39.565 2082-2082/com.auxxa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.auxxa, PID: 2082
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.auxxa/com.auxxa.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.auxxa.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.auxxa.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/reactnativenavigation/controllers/SplashActivity;
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.auxxa-kepsg_14aZ2UYrvnEZNCVA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

> Here I have attched me application log.It is showing a error likejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class .This error came suddenly.I did not update any versions or any thing .How can I solve this issue.